# Quel est la différence entre "savoir" et "pouvoir" en général ?

Tags: vocabulaire

Which one is correct in this context? *Sais* or *peux*?

> Nous cherchons un musicien pour jouer dans notre groupe.
>
> Marc, tu..... jouer de la guitare, non?

Answer (score 3):

> Tu peux jouer de la guitare.

You are able to play the guitar (physically).

> Tu sais jouer de la guitare.

You know how to play the guitar.

As another example,  compare

> Je ne sais pas conduire.

and

> Ayant bu de l'alcool, je ne peux pas conduire.

As a question:

> Sais-tu jouer de la guitare ?
>
> Tu sais jouer de la guitare ?
>
> Est-ce que tu sais jouer de la guitare ?

Etc.

**Savoir**, with a **noun** or **pronoun** object or **introducing a clause** means know in the sense of being **aware of, having learnt, or having been informed about**.

> Je sais la réponse.
>
> Il savait sa leçon.
>
> Savez-vous son nom ?
>
> Je sais comment le faire.
>
> Savez-vous l'heure du train ?
>
> Elle ne savait pas s'il viendrait.
>
> On sait qu'elle est partie pendant la nuit.
>
> Je n'ai su que dire. Je n'ai pas su quoi dire.

**Savoir** governing an **infinitive**, has the sense of know how to (can) and its usage must be distinguished from **pouvoir** which means **can** in the sense of (being) **physically able to**. Cf.

> Elle ne sait pas conduire. (She cannot drive = She doesn't know to drive.)
>
> Elle ne peut pas conduire. (She cannot drive (because of physical inability.)

In carefully French, the **conditional of savoir**, in the **negative**, but without **pas**, may be used to render the negative present tense of pouvoir.

> Je ne saurais l'expliquer. I cannot account for it.

**Connaitre** on the other hand, means **know** in the sense of **being familiar with, having an understanding of**.

> Il connait le droit, l'espagnol.
>
> Je connais cet homme, cette ville, le chemin, le bonheur.

(Reference: Ferrar, H., A French Reference Grammar, Oxford University Press)

Comment: merci à vous. So I should use the verb "savoir" in my example.

Comment: It's not only a question of physical capability. How can you know something ? For having learnt it. I learnt to play piano. I **know** that. Je **sais** jouer du piano.  However, I also played with several other instruments without any specific learning. If necessary, I can play, Je **peux** jouer... si nécessaire, pour dépanner... Mais... dans les faits, je ne **sais** pas en jouer.

Comment: @elli : Si tu veux cherches un pro en tant que membre permanent, mieux vaut utiliser *savoir*. Si tu cherches quelqu'un pour faire office occasionnellement, pour te dépanner alors... *pouvoir* suffit.

Comment: Noter que la suggestion de @Strangelovian convient très bien... entre pros.

Comment: @aCOSwt merci à votre joli explication. J'ai trouvé cet exemple dans mon livre français. donc je n'ai pas plus d'informations sur la question.

Comment: @aCOSwt According to my grammar books savoir (governing an infinitive) has the sense of know how whilst pouvoir means being physically able to. Both of them can be rendered by the English can. See my edited answer.

Comment: @dimitris : Oui! Tu as raison... en général. Mais le milieu de la musique a ses codes particuliers.

Comment: Ok, maintenant je comprends:-)! Je m'excuse de t'avoir mal compris.

Comment: j'aimerais ajouter que parfois, en Belgique francophone, `sais` est parfois utilisé à la place de `peux`. Par exemple, il n'est pas si rare d'entendre `est-ce que tu saurais me passer le sel ?` à la place de `est-ce que tu pourrais me passer le sel ?`

Answer (score 3):

In this context, ***savoir jouer*** means being knowledgeable in guitar playing while ***pouvoir jouer*** means that nothing prevents the person from playing the guitar.

What might prevent Marc from playing can be either a physical /psychological limitation or some external constraint (prohibition).

Here are the various cases:

---

> *Marc, tu sais jouer de la guitare ?*

A. Have you learn how to play the guitar (are you a skilled guitarist)?

---

> *Marc, tu peux jouer de la guitare ?*

B. Is a personal limitation/disability preventing you to play the guitar?

C. Are you allowed to play the guitar?

---

Pouvoir can also be used to politely ask someone to do something:

> *Marc, tu peux jouer de la guitare, s'il te plait ?*

D. Would you mind playing the guitar, please?

---

Note that if the question is asked in Belgium, *savoir* would be used for A., B. and D. and *pouvoir* would only be used for C.

e.g.

> *Marc, tu sais jouer de la guitare, s'il te plait?* (D.)

Comment: @jilliagre merci. What about this example? Rosa est allée étudier pendant un an à Berlin. Elle ....parler allemand maintenant. peux ou sait?!

Comment: Studying provides knowledge so the most logical choice is *sait*.

Answer (score 2):

I would put it more simply:

> Marc, joues-tu de la guitare?

Comment: +1 pour la formulation correcte... entre pros. Il y a juste un risque si on s'adresse à un dilettante qui pourrait *croire* qu'il *joue* et répondre par l'affirmative... ;-)

Comment: *Joues-tu* is  written or formal spoken French. This kind of negation is unexpected in the question's context.

Comment: @jlliagre : Il est des codes entre musicos qui dépassent ou ignorent ces conditions de formalisme auxquelles tu fais référence. *Jouer* en fait partie.

Comment: @jlliagre : & BTW, what do you mean with *this kind of negation* ?

Comment: @aCOSwt My point wasn't about *jouer* but about the pronoun/verb inversion. The fact is almost no native French uses it in real life spoken French (except French teachers, but they teach written French). I expect a conversation between musicians/people who know each other to be relaxed and avoid the inversion formalism.

Answer (score 2):

**1.** Marc, tu **sais** jouer de la guitare, non?

**2.** La différence entre « savoir faire qqc » et « pouvoir faire qqc » est une question de possibilités intellectuelles/artistiques ou dans un sport d'adresse (1) opposées à des possibilités matérielles (2). Lorsque l'on utilise le premier on peut souvent utiliser le second mais pas vice versa. Des cas difficiles à trancher existent.

On comprend que lorsque « savoir » est un usage possible « pouvoir » le soit aussi  en cela que pour toute possibilité de type (1) correspond une réalisation matérielle (2).

**3.** Exemples

- Il n'a que quatre ans et demi mais il **sait/peut** déjà faire des additions.
- Le petit chien **sait/peut** faire des tours surprenants, c'est un chien de cirque.
- Ce jeune artiste **sait/peut** jongler avec dix balles.
- C'est un athlète qui **peut** soulever 250 kg. (*« Savoir » ne peut pas être utilisé.*)
- Est-ce que vous *pouvez* jouer de la guitare sans regarder le manche? (*« savoir » ne semble pas justifié ni souhaitable, il semble que dans ce cas les français et même des personnes d'autres nationalités, dans leur langue maternelle, préfèrerons utiliser « pouvoir »; je pense à l'anglais : Can you play your guitar without looking at the frets?*)
- Est-ce que tu **peux** jouer de la guitare ce soir? Il nous faut un remplaçant… (*« Savoir » n'aurait pas de sens. Cet exemple est un peu spécial comme la possibilité n'implique pas la connaissance de l'instrument*)
- Ces archers  **peuvent** tous  placer leurs flèches dans le troisième cercle. (*Bien qu'il soit question d'adresse, dans ce cas particulier on utilise difficilement le verbe « savoir ».)